# Confusion about Blocking Queue and Multi-thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I was learning Producer-Consumer pattern with multiple threads.
The basic idea is one producer thread will put data into the Blocking Queue, and then many consumer threads will take data from the queue.

The consumer's "run()" method is shown below.

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        List<String> record;
        while(true) {
            if(this.channel.getState()) {
                break;
            }
            try {
//                System.out.println(this.channel.getSharedQueue().size());
                record = this.channel.getSharedQueue().take();
                ...
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        record = null;
    }
```

When I comment out the "System.out.println(...)", the whole program will get stuck.
However, if "System.out.println(...)" is added, the program will run smoothly.
Can someone help explain the magic behind "System.out.println(...)" ?

Here is the producer's "run()" method.

```
    public void run() {
        ...
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && line.length() > 1) {
                List<String> record = parseRow(line);
                if(record != null)
                    this.channel.getSharedQueue().put(record);
            }
        ...
        this.channel.setState(true);
    }
```

And the main method.

```
        ExecutorService producerExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Runnable producer = new Producer(channel, ...);
        producerExecutor.execute(producer);

        ExecutorService consumerExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);
        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            Runnable consumer = new Consumer(channel);
            consumerExecutor.execute(consumer);
        }

        consumerExecutor.shutdown();
        producerExecutor.shutdown();
        while (!consumerExecutor.isTerminated() || !producerExecutor.isTerminated());
```

The Channel class is like

```
public class Channel {

    private volatile boolean state;

    ...

    public boolean getState() {
        return this.state;
    }

    public void setState(boolean state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `System.out.println` synchronizes internally on the underlying output stream. That is just an implementation detail, but can have such effects in multithreaded code.

Comment: There could be multiple problems. Are `channel` and `SessionManager` standard classes, or are they custom classes? One possible problem might be changes to `channel.state` not being published correctly.

Comment: ```channel.state``` is volatile boolean.

Comment: Could you post the whole necessary code to reproduce the problem? Would help us (me) much to simply copy paste the stuff in my IDE and find the issue easier.

Comment: I assume the reader `br` (and the underlying resource) is distinct for each thread?

Comment: There is a single producer (where br stays) thread and multiple consumer threads.